# Continuously stream output from grep

Tags: logging, grep, streaming

I have a log that's continuously being written to, and I want to print lines from it like this

```
grep 'StringPatter'  my_file.log | tail -f
```

However, after this command runs initially, it just exits, rather than continuously stream. What's the solution?

Note that I have coloring `html` in the file, stuff like `ESC[31mZNU6` , so I also want them to be properly displayed.

Comment: first tail then grep

Comment: tail -f file | grep --line-buffered my_pattern

Comment: Thanks Rafal, that works.

Comment: @Rafal : IMHO, `tail ..| grep ..` & `grep ..| tail ..` are not the same !

Comment: @blackSmith I'm aware of that but it seems to me that author of this question needed tail | grep.